# Google maps distance matrix api header

Tags: google-distancematrix-api

How to deal with the fact that the Google Maps Distance Matrix API does not send the "access-control-allow-origin" header like Google Maps Geocoding API does it.

I have problem using XMLHttpRequest().

Comment: care to show some code?

Comment: I resolve this situation by adding the "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin:* " extension to chrome. After you add it, you will see an icon in green with the letters "cors" in the upper right corner. Now it's working pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this situation by adding the "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin:* " extension to chrome. After you add it, you will see an icon in green with the letters "cors" in the upper right corner. Now it's working pretty well.

Comment: Well, this may solve the problem for you but you can't force your users to add extensions to their browsers.